# Does someone know the name of this equipment?

Tags: physical-chemistry, equipment

[image]

I think it is used to measure force or something like that. I broke it and have to buy a new one.

Comment: Googling for "spring force meter" led me to this page, is it what you are looking for? http://www.carolina.com/spring-scales/force-meter-spring-balances/FAM_954440.pr

Comment: This questions seems to belong to Physics S.E.

Answer (score 3):

There are different equipment used to measure force like pivot balance, strain gauge, spring balance, etc.

By seeing the image, we can easily figure out it is **spring balance**.

[image]